# Алгоритм присваивания отрицательных значений какой-либо переменной в памяти

Tags: java, операторы, cpu, ram, оператор-присваивания

К примеру, мне известно о том, что все отрицательные числа представляются в памяти посредством дополнительного кода. Как это происходит? Русскоязычная терминология немного отличается от той, которая была принята на Западе, поэтому было бы правильнее придерживаться таких понятий, как первое (обратный код) и второе дополнения, чтобы не нарушать канонов. С положительными значениями особых вопросов не возникает, так как прямой, обратный и дополнительный код для этих значений абсолютно не отличается. А вот теперь мы и подошли к первому вопросу. Меня интересует сам алгоритм присваивания отрицательных значений какой-либо переменной. Поскольку я изучаю язык программирования *Java*, то хотелось бы получить ответ именно в данном контексте (хотя я думаю, что для других языков разницы также не будет, так как все операции физически осуществляются на уровне микропроцессора). Правильно ли я понимаю, что за данное действие отвечает АЛУ (*арифметико-логическое устройство*)? Или же какой-то другой блок процессора?

Здесь мне хотелось бы описать небольшой пример того, как я понимаю алгоритм присваивания значения переменной. Допустим, что в нашем абстрактном коде имеется следующая инструкция:

```
byte b = -5;
```

Изначально значение записывается в прямом коде, где старший бит является фиксированным знаковым битом, который используется для кодирования знака числового значения в знаковых типах данных. Получаем следующее двоичное представление:

```
1000 0101
```

Затем мы получаем первое дополнение (обратный код). Для этого мы применяем инверсию для каждого значащего разряда, которые участвуют в формировании самого числового значения. Значение старшего разряда мы оставляем прежним. В результате инвертирования битов получаем такой результат:

```
1111 1010
```

После чего мы добавляем к нашему результату *1*, что и является вторым и результирующим дополнением. В конечном итоге, в память будет помещено двоичное число, которое соответствует числу *-5* в десятичной системе счисления:

```
1111 1011
```

Но это всё лишь в моём представлении... Скажите, пожалуйста, насколько я прав? И действительно ли обработкой всех этих операций занимается именно АЛУ? Если же я прав, то значит ли это, что современные процессоры фактически не используют операцию вычитания при арифметических расчётах?

И еще вопрос, у меня уже давно возникла небольшая путаница с пониманием термина *машинное слово*. В той же Википедии написано, что данная величина зависит от разрядности регистров процессора. А от чего в свою очередь зависит эта разрядность? От типа данных в конкретном языке программирования? Правильно ли я понимаю, что величина машинного слова типа `byte` в языке программирования *Java* составляет ***8*** бит, `short` и `char` по ***16*** бит, а `int` ***32*** бита?

Comment: Ничего не напутали? byte` - от 0 до 255, не может быть отрицательным.

Comment: Нет, не напутал. В языке программирования Java примитивный целочисленный тип данных `byte` является знаковым типом данных и ограничен таким диапазоном значений [-128; 127].

Comment: Если брать в расчёт все существующие в языке программирования Java целочисленные типы данных, то беззнаковым типом данных (unsigned type) является исключительно тип данных `char`, диапазон возможных значений которого представляет [0; 65535].

Comment: Современные процессоры полны всяких хитростей. Так они не умножают на 2, а делают битовый сдвиг, о прочих не знаю. 
В памяти хранятся именно числа с инвертирующим битом, все остальные операции проходит на АЛУ. При этом вычисление обратного кода не отнимает дополнительных тактов(мне так кажется). Это базовая логика. Открывается нужный вентиль и числа инвертируются. Ну а у АЛУ может быть два различных управляющих сигнала, когда на один подается сигнал - производится бесзнаковое сложение, а когда на второй - знаковое

Comment: В машинном понимании чисел это просто биты информации, которые складываются в байты которые делятся пополам на отрицательные и положительные числа. Из таких же чисел состоят и байткоды которые оперируют с числами на уровне JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, смена знака в дополнительном коде производится инверсией битов и прибавлением единицы.

> как я понимаю алгоритм присваивания значения переменной

Нет, не совсем так. Присваивание

```
byte b = -5;
```

не генерирует арифметических команд, только непосредственно присваивание значения 0xFB (-5). Любые арифметические выражения с константами сворачиваются на этапе компиляции.

> И действительно ли обработкой всех этих операций занимается именно
>   АЛУ?

Да, всей арифметикой занимается АЛУ, кто же еще. За исключением вычислений на этапе компиляции (которые в конечном итоге тоже выполняются АЛУ).

> значит ли это, что современные процессоры фактически не используют
>   операцию вычитания при арифметических расчётах?

Конечно, используют. Хотя вычитание можно выполнять в две команды - инверсия знака + сложение, одна команда вычитания выполняется быстрее. Но вот на уровне микропрограммы процессор может вычитание и не делать.

> И еще вопрос, у меня уже давно возникла небольшая путаница с
>   пониманием термина машинное слово. В той же Википедии написано, что
>   данная величина зависит от разрядности регистров процессора. А от чего
>   в свою очередь зависит эта разрядность?

Разрядность зависит от архитектуры процессора. У 32-разрядных процессоров машинное слово длиной 32 бита. У 64-разрядных соответственно 64 бита. Язык программирования тут не при чем, это аппаратная характеристика процессора.

Comment: Крайне благодарен за столь подробный ответ! Не до конца разобрался с машинными словами... Можете привести небольшой пример в контексте языка программирования Java? Вот смотрите, насколько я понимаю, то подавляющее большинство настольных ЭВМ функционируют на архитектуре *x86-64*, которая является расширением более ранней архитектуры *x86*. Вы же написали, что величина машинного слова зависит от архитектуры процессора, с чем я целиком и полностью согласен. Выходит, что размер машинного слова для моего процессора на архитектуре *x86-64* составляет 64 бита.

Comment: Поехали дальше! Что из себя представляют эти 64 бита на физическом уровне? Это размер регистра процессора? Если можно, то ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: И правильно ли я понял, что размер переменных в том же языке программирования *Java* не имеет никакого отношения к размерности машинного слова? Если это исключительно аппаратная характеристика, то значит ли это, что установка 32-х битной операционной системы не повлияет на размер машинного слова? Или всё-таки повлияет?

Comment: @Lexoid, "*размер машинного слова для моего процессора на архитектуре x86-64 составляет 64 бита*" - не совсем так. В процессе эволюции x86 перешел на 64 бита, но для совместимости остался и 32-битовый режим. То есть x86-64 по сути две независимых архитектуры. Когда процессор функционирует под 32-битовой ОС, он 32-битовы, и размер машинного слова 32 бита. Когда он работает под 64-битовой ОС, соответственно 64-бита. Но при этом он может выполнять в виртуальной машине 32-битовые приложения и для них он 32-битовый с 32-битовым машинным словом. Выглядит шизофренично, но так уж сложилось исторически

Comment: @Lexoid, переменные какого-то конкретного языка программирования слабо зависят от размера машинного слова. Например, если язык предоставляет 64-битовое целое, а процессор 32-битовый, язык просто эмулирует 64 бита арифметикой двойной точности. По большому счету, программисту мало интересен размер машинного слова, если только он не работает на низком уровне или озабочен оптимизацией. Размер машинного слова - это разрядность регистров, или можно сказать, разрядность арифметических операций. Какого размера операнды можно просуммировать одной машинной командой сложения.

Comment: Чудесное пояснение! Я хоть и не работаю с низкоуровневыми представлениями программ, но мне, тем не менее, очень интересно знать, что же на самом деле происходит за кулисами. А вся эта путаница возникла по той простой причине, что я изначально не совсем правильно воспринял некоторые фундаментальные понятия, которые вполне успешно перемешались в моей голове и превратились в настоящую кашу! Смотрите, мне хотелось бы как-то прорезюмировать тот весьма полезный опыт, которым Вы со мной поделились.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю модель памяти Java, то содержимое всех локальных переменных, а также полей, которые являются статическими членами класса, помещается в стековую память, которая, в свою очередь, является непосредственной частью RAM. Термин «машинное слово» корректно применять исключительно к регистрам, которые к RAM уже не имеют никакого отношения, но, в то же время, являются сверхбыстрой ОЗУ внутри процессора (крайне надеюсь, что Вы меня поняли). Что же тогда помещается в регистры в ходе выполнения какой-нибудь произвольной компьютерной программы?

Comment: Вы чуть выше упомянули операнды арифметических операций. Правильно ли я понял, что в регистры помещаются сами операнды, а затем с ними проводятся определённые арифметические операции при помощи АЛУ? Или там происходит что-то другое? Могли бы Вы привести наглядный пример? Благодарю!

Comment: @Lexoid, зависит от конкретной архитектуры. Обычно поддерживаются режимы адресации (то есть откуда команда берет операнды) регистр-регистр и регистр-память. Но некоторые архитектуры поддерживают также режим память-память, а некоторые разрешают только регистровые команды. Выгоднее держать  операнды в регистрах, потому что регистры - это часть процессора. Конкретно у x86 регистров мало и компиляторы выполняют довольно сложную оптимизацию, чтобы минимизировать обращения к памяти. Хотя с развитием кеш памяти разница между памятью и регистрами уменьшилась. Результат сохраняется в один из операндов.

Comment: А если взять x86-64? Как там происходит? Там размер регистров в 2 раза больше, если мы работаем под 64-битной операционной системой. Свободного места должно хватать. Значит ли это, что операнды в вышеуказанной архитектуре хранятся именно в регистрах?

Comment: @Lexoid, размер регистра тут неважен, потому что один регистр = один операнд. И регистров там все равно мало, многие используются и для адресации. Много регистров в RISC архитектуре, там такая концепция. А в CISC (в x64) с регистрами всегда нехватка.

Comment: Да, это я понимаю. Но ведь несомненным плюсом является то, что в такой регистр можно спокойно поместить 64-битный операнд и нам уже не нужна никакая арифметика с двойной точностью. Или же я не прав?

Comment: @Lexoid, Да, 64-битная арифметика будет выполняться быстрее, но она нужна довольно редко, так что разницы мало. По скорости 64-битная программа не быстрее 32-битной, может даже чуть медленнее. Преимущество 64 бит в расширенной адресации - 32-битная Win программа может адресовать только 2гб, и многим программам этого не хватает.

Comment: То есть, если мы запустим наше Java-приложение на 64-разрядной операционной системе, то в вычислительном процессе будет использоваться именно 64-битная арифметика? Аналогично и с 32-разрядной ОС, там, очевидно, будет выполняться уже 32-битная арифметика.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87156/discussion-between-freim-and-lexoid).

Answer (score 1):

Главное преимущество дополнительного кода в том что сложение и вычитание работают одинаково как с положительными так и с отрицательными числами.

```
-1      = 1111 1111
1       = 0000 0001
1  + 1  = 0000 0010
-1 + 1  = 0000 0000 -- из-за переполнения.
-1 + -1 = 1111 1110
```

Comment: Переполнение в операциях сложения/вычитания невозможно (или, точнее, неопределимо). Выход бита за разрядную сетку называется переносом (carry), и это совершенно нормальное явление для арифметики в дополнительном коде. Этот бит не отбрасывается, а просто переходит в флаг переноса (который по сути есть расширение разрядной сетки).

Comment: Уважаемый freim! Если можно, то хотелось бы получить от Вас разъяснения и по этому вопросу. Почитал немного про битовые флаги и картинка в голове начала потихоньку складываться. Только я немного не понял, где именно находится этот бит. К примеру, мы выделяем для хранения некоторого числового значения 8 бит памяти, что соответствует примитивному целочисленному типу данных *byte* в языке программирования *Java*. Сама же переменная представляет собой абстрактное понятие, которое на физическом уровне соответствует некоторой адресуемой области памяти.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то *флаг переноса* можно рассматривать, как девятый бит результата. Где же он будет располагаться в памяти? Непосредственно напротив того октета к которому он имеет отношение? Или как? Мне просто тяжеловато себе это представить. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь!

Comment: @Lexoid, флаг переноса располагается не в памяти. Существует специальные регистр флагов, в котором все они и собраны - переноса, знака, нуля, переполнения, и т.д. Для работы с флагами есть специальные команды, прежде всего условные переходы (для бита переноса они тоже есть). И специально для арифметики многократной точности есть сложение с переносом - `ra = rb + carry`. Но для программиста на языке высокого уровня это лишние знания, вот если начнете писать на ассемблере, тогда все это будете знать наизусть.

Comment: @Lexoid, флаги меняются после каждой команды. То есть флаг переноса это действительно дополнительный бит, но он временный. Если программа его не использовала (для условного перехода, например), он изменится после выполнения следующей команды.

Comment: Знания может быть и лишние, но всё равно крайне интересно! Кто знает, может быть в будущем ещё пригодится! :) Почитал немного на эту тему и вроде бы пришло озарение. Я так понимаю, что флаг переноса это просто отдельный бит в регистре флагов. Для архитектуры *x86-64* данный регистр имеет размер 64-бита и имеет название своё оригинальное название RFLAGS. А теперь мне хотелось бы понять как же это работает на практике...

Comment: Допустим, что у нас имеется следующая операция: byte a = 1; byte b = (byte) (127 + a); Очевидно, что в данном примере у нас как раз происходит выход бита за разрядную сетку. Я так понимаю, что именно в процессе выполнения данной операции  *Overflow Flag* в регистре флагов устанавливается в положение 1. Верно? И куда этот бит потом идёт? На что он влияет? Влияет на флаг знака?

Comment: @freim, если можно, то здесь я также ожидаю Вашего ответа! :)

Comment: @Lexoid, нет, флаг переполнения там не установится. Переполнение при сложении невозможно (точнее, процессор не может его определить). Будет установлен только CF (carry flag). Он будет изменен при следующей операции, которая влияет на CF. Флаги ни на что не влияют, они просто есть. Но некоторые команды их используют. Например команда JC выпоняет условный переход если CF установлен.

Comment: @freim Не уверен, но кажется понял. Это бит необходим для такого рода операцией. Когда там необходимо выполнить сложение таких 8-битных чисел `11111111` и `0000001`. Старший разряд уйдёт в флаг переноса, а результат будет `00000000` в двоичной системе счисления.

Comment: @Lexoid, верно. Заметьте, что процессор не в состоянии определить, складывались ли -1 и +1, и в результате нормально получился 0, или же складывали 255 и 1, и в результате произошло переполнение. Только программист знает что он складывал и может определить было ли переполнение.

Comment: @freim Благодарю, с этим теперь разобрался! :)